# How can I get swap files for new/unsaved files/code in empty buffers? Any way to recover unsaved files?

Tags: vimrc

I'm trying to configure Vim to make it so that if my system crashes I can recover my work from swap files set in `set directory=`.

I tested this out on Vim in Windows using gVim. If I forcibly crash Vim to test this out, when I reopen vim I get an alert about my swap files like so: 
`'Swap file "~\.vim\scratch_files\swap//C%%Path%To%WorkingDirectory%Filename.txt.swp" already exists!'`
`[Open Read-Only] [Edit anyway] [Recover] [Delete it] [Quit] [Abort]`

However, it only recovers files that I have previously saved. Anything that I had in an **empty buffer** prior to when it was saved (any unsaved files) doesn't have a swap to recover.

Is there a way to get Vim to create swap files for **new files** I hadn't yet saved? / Is there any way to recover new files after a crash?

Comment: I believe swap files for unnamed buffers are just called `.swp`, `.swo`, etc. You can use `:recover .swp` to recover from the file `.swp` in the current directory.

Comment: There was no .swp file created unfortunately. I'm not sure why.